# Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout) error in jenkins with xvfb mode

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

When I run `Selenium - Ruby` tests in **xvfb** mode against `jenkins`, the scripts go unreliable and randomly throws same error in different steps.

```
Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

any workaround for this issue? or any retry exceptions for every function using cucumber in ruby

[image]

Comment: This error happens when click and loading of following page takes more than 60 seconds, right?

Comment: Yea we know that. The same script works fine on real browser; but throws error in xvfb mode while executing the scripts in virtual machine through CI

Comment: Oh Okay, sorry, I don't have any idea about that.